# Pympler behaves strangely

Tags: python, memory-leaks

Pympler is used to find memory leaks in python but when I run this program:

```
from pympler import muppy

for i in range(10):
    objs = muppy.get_objects()
    print(len(objs))
```

the output is:

```
31703
31704
31705
31706
31707
31708
31709
31710
31711
31712
```

In every iteration, the number of objects has increased! If I run it for a long time, I would run out of memory! What is happening? Does pympler have memory leak itself?!

---

**Update:**
The same thing happens with the following program:

```
import gc

for i in range(10):
    objs = gc.get_objects()
    print(len(objs))
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you will run out of memory after several iterations? I could imagine that the `objs` collection also counts as an object but is not immediately collected by the GC...

Comment: After the update: Try running `gc.collect()` after every iteration and see if the number of objects remains the same. Just do that for debugging, there is (almost) no need to run it in production code.

Comment: @jojonas Yes. I ran it for 1000 iterations; it keeps increasing!

Comment: @jojonas Calling `gc.collect()` doesn't help. Still increases.

Comment: Interestingly, adding the line `objs = None` to the end of the loop prevents the number of objects from incrementing.

Comment: Calling `gc.collect()` doesn't reduce the count, but setting `objs = None` appears to dereference all of the previous `muppy.get_objects()` objects.

Comment: Also, unsurprisingly, if the loop is put into a function, the count will increment there, but then reverts to the original count when the function scope is left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what's going on:

The increasing number indeed comes from the `objs` collection itself.

When the loop is called the second (!) time, the `objs` object from the last iteration is still in scope. Therefore, it will be not removed by GC. Thus, the collection of objects `objs` now also contains the (older) `objs` object itself, leading to the count being incremented.

If you call `del objs` or `objs = None` or anything else *before* calling `gc.get_objects()`/`muppy.get_objects()`, you will get the same count on each iteration:

```
import gc

for i in range(10):
    objs = None
    objs = gc.get_objects()
    print(len(objs))
```

Gives `7063` on each iteration (on my system).